# How to sort an array based off another array which holds the indexes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have array a that holds the position of what the array b should.

```
a = [3, 2, 0, 1]
b = ["hello", "hi", 2332, "ben"]
```

I want to sort b so that it will become

```
["ben", 2332, "hello", "hi"]
```

where it get's its index from array a.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [Array#values_at](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at)

```
b = ["hello", "hi", 2332, "ben"]
a = [3, 2, 0, 1]

p b.values_at(*a)  # => ["ben", 2332, "hello", "hi"]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was trying to do it using sort, index and map but it didn't work out for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use `map` here is how to:

```
b = ["hello", "hi", 2332, "ben"]
a = [3, 2, 0, 1]
a.map{|i| b[i]}  # => ["ben", 2332, "hello", "hi"]
```